# Integrate and NIntegrate give different results

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Good morning,
i computed the following integral using Integrate and i get a different result from the one obtained with NIntegrate.
Here is the integrand

```
 expr = (b (b - 2 d + Sqrt[4 + b^2 - 4 b d]) (c + I x) x (3 + b^2 c^2 + 2 I b^2 c x - (-6 + b^2) x^2 + 3 x^4) (-1 + a x (-2 I c + a x)))/((2 + b^2 + 2 d (d - Sqrt[4 + b^2 - 4 b d]) + b (-4 d + Sqrt[4 + b^2 - 4 b d])) \[Pi]^3 (-I c + a x) (1 - b c -I b x + x^2)^2 (1 + b c + I b x + x^2)^2 (1 + a^2 x^2));`
```

I use Integrate

```
result = Integrate[expr, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> 1/2 (b + Sqrt[4 + b^2 - 4 b d]) > -1 && 1/2 (b + Sqrt[4 + b^2 - 4 b d]) < 1 && c > -1 && c < 1 && d > 1 &&
 a >= 0]
```

and then i compare the results

```
 result/.{a->2,b->0.65,c->0.25,d->1.7} 0.341887 +0. I NIntegrate[expr/.{a->2,b->0.65,c->0.25,d->1.7},{x,-Infinity,Infinity}] -0.00340441-8.67362*10^-19 I
```

As you can see i get different results even if the assumptions are satisfied. Why?

Comment: Your numerical result is correct. Use `FullSimplify`, remove the constant pre-factor and use the `Rubi` package in order to integrate analytically.

Comment: @yarchik: Can you elaborate your directions?  In particular, can you ground "Your numerical result is correct"? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 See below, but it takes a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the right analytical result quite fast, if you impose the addidional condition `b<1` . Maybe Integrate then finds an other branch.

```
expr = (b (b - 2 d + Sqrt[4 + b^2 - 4 b d]) (c + I x) x (3 + 
   b^2 c^2 + 2 I b^2 c x - (-6 + b^2) x^2 + 3 x^4) (-1 + 
   a x (-2 I c + a x)))/((2 + b^2 + 
   2 d (d - Sqrt[4 + b^2 - 4 b d]) + 
   b (-4 d + Sqrt[4 + b^2 - 4 b d])) \[Pi]^3 (-I c + 
   a x) (1 - b c - I b x + x^2)^2 (1 + b c + I b x + x^2)^2 (1 + 
   a^2 x^2));

asump = 1/2 (b + Sqrt[4 + b^2 - 4 b d]) > -1 && 
        1/2 (b + Sqrt[4 + b^2 - 4 b d]) < 1 && c > -1 && c < 1 && d > 1 && 
        a >= 0;

red = Reduce[asump && b < 1, {a, b, c, d}, Reals]

result = Integrate[expr, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> red]

result /. {a -> 2, b -> 0.65, c -> 0.25, d -> 1.7}

(*   -0.00340441 + 0. I   *)

NIntegrate[
  expr /. {a -> 2, b -> 0.65, c -> 0.25, d -> 1.7}, {x, -Infinity, 
Infinity}]
```

The same !

```
result  (*   version 8.0   *)

(*   ConditionalExpression[(2 I b ((8192 (20 a b^3 + 32 a^3 b^3 - 
       36 a^5 b^3 + 15 a b^5 + 200 a^3 b^5 - 111 a^5 b^5 - 
       a b^7 + 208 a^3 b^7 - 78 a^5 b^7 - a b^9 + 72 a^3 b^9 - 
       9 a^5 b^9 + 8 a^3 b^11 + 5 a^5 b^11 + a^5 b^13 + 8 b^2 c + 
       24 a b^2 c + 16 a^2 b^2 c - 24 a^4 b^2 c - 24 a^5 b^2 c + 
       30 b^4 c + 82 a b^4 c + 212 a^2 b^4 c + 512 a^3 b^4 c - 
       154 a^4 b^4 c - 330 a^5 b^4 c + 12 b^6 c + 10 a b^6 c + 
       258 a^2 b^6 c + 1208 a^3 b^6 c - 104 a^4 b^6 c - 
       516 a^5 b^6 c + b^8 c - 8 a b^8 c + 92 a^2 b^8 c + 
       672 a^3 b^8 c + 32 a^4 b^8 c - 162 a^5 b^8 c + 
       10 a^2 b^10 c + 104 a^3 b^10 c + 32 a^4 b^10 c + 
       30 a^5 b^10 c + 5 a^4 b^12 c + 12 a^5 b^12 c + 
       84 b^3 c^2 + 156 a b^3 c^2 + 360 a^2 b^3 c^2 + 
       136 a^3 b^3 c^2 - 316 a^4 b^3 c^2 - 180 a^5 b^3 c^2 + 
       87 b^5 c^2 + 193 a b^5 c^2 + 1278 a^2 b^5 c^2 + 
       1870 a^3 b^5 c^2 - 665 a^4 b^5 c^2 - 915 a^5 b^5 c^2 + 
       13 b^7 c^2 + 34 a b^7 c^2 + 798 a^2 b^7 c^2 + 
       2124 a^3 b^7 c^2 + 10 a^4 b^7 c^2 - 684 a^5 b^7 c^2 + 
       6 a b^9 c^2 + 126 a^2 b^9 c^2 + 518 a^3 b^9 c^2 + 
       259 a^4 b^9 c^2 + 15 a^5 b^9 c^2 + 2 a^3 b^11 c^2 + 
       61 a^4 b^11 c^2 + 54 a^5 b^11 c^2 + 24 b^2 c^3 + 
       56 a b^2 c^3 + 48 a^2 b^2 c^3 - 48 a^3 b^2 c^3 - 
       72 a^4 b^2 c^3 - 8 a^5 b^2 c^3 + 162 b^4 c^3 + 
       578 a b^4 c^3 + 1524 a^2 b^4 c^3 + 460 a^3 b^4 c^3 - 
       934 a^4 b^4 c^3 - 430 a^5 b^4 c^3 + 54 b^6 c^3 + 
       404 a b^6 c^3 + 2232 a^2 b^6 c^3 + 2448 a^3 b^6 c^3 - 
       474 a^4 b^6 c^3 - 972 a^5 b^6 c^3 + 72 a b^8 c^3 + 
       582 a^2 b^8 c^3 + 1188 a^3 b^8 c^3 + 698 a^4 b^8 c^3 - 
       178 a^5 b^8 c^3 + 20 a^3 b^10 c^3 + 284 a^4 b^10 c^3 + 
       112 a^5 b^10 c^3 + 60 b^3 c^4 + 368 a b^3 c^4 + 
       312 a^2 b^3 c^4 - 232 a^3 b^3 c^4 - 244 a^4 b^3 c^4 - 
       24 a^5 b^3 c^4 + 81 b^5 c^4 + 964 a b^5 c^4 + 
       2178 a^2 b^5 c^4 + 474 a^3 b^5 c^4 - 763 a^4 b^5 c^4 - 
       414 a^5 b^5 c^4 + 304 a b^7 c^4 + 1188 a^2 b^7 c^4 + 
       1140 a^3 b^7 c^4 + 706 a^4 b^7 c^4 - 315 a^5 b^7 c^4 + 
       70 a^3 b^9 c^4 + 631 a^4 b^9 c^4 + 105 a^5 b^9 c^4 + 
       16 a b^2 c^5 - 16 a^3 b^2 c^5 + 32 b^4 c^5 + 
       636 a b^4 c^5 + 504 a^2 b^4 c^5 - 348 a^3 b^4 c^5 - 
       224 a^4 b^4 c^5 - 24 a^5 b^4 c^5 + 528 a b^6 c^5 + 
       1002 a^2 b^6 c^5 + 192 a^3 b^6 c^5 + 204 a^4 b^6 c^5 - 
       138 a^5 b^6 c^5 + 100 a^3 b^8 c^5 + 683 a^4 b^8 c^5 + 
       36 a^5 b^8 c^5 + 48 a b^3 c^6 - 32 a^3 b^3 c^6 + 
       324 a b^5 c^6 + 240 a^2 b^5 c^6 - 160 a^3 b^5 c^6 - 
       4 a^4 b^5 c^6 - 8 a^5 b^5 c^6 + 50 a^3 b^7 c^6 + 
       325 a^4 b^7 c^6 + 2 a^5 b^7 c^6 + 32 a b^4 c^7 - 
       16 a^3 b^4 c^7 + 4 a^3 b^6 c^7 + 48 a^4 b^6 c^7 + 
       4 I a b^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       4 I a^5 b^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       11 I a b^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       56 I a^3 b^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       39 I a^5 b^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       I a b^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       112 I a^3 b^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       50 I a^5 b^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       I a b^8 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       56 I a^3 b^8 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       13 I a^5 b^8 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       8 I a^3 b^10 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       3 I a^5 b^10 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       I a^5 b^12 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       12 I b^3 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       32 I a b^3 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       48 I a^2 b^3 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       64 I a^3 b^3 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       44 I a^4 b^3 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       64 I a^5 b^3 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       10 I b^5 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       16 I a b^5 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       134 I a^2 b^5 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       456 I a^3 b^5 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       76 I a^4 b^5 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       224 I a^5 b^5 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       I b^7 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       6 I a b^7 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       72 I a^2 b^7 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       416 I a^3 b^7 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       2 I a^4 b^7 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       132 I a^5 b^7 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       10 I a^2 b^9 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       88 I a^3 b^9 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       22 I a^4 b^9 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       8 I a^5 b^9 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       5 I a^4 b^11 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       10 I a^5 b^11 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       12 I b^2 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       20 I a b^2 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       24 I a^2 b^2 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       8 I a^3 b^2 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       36 I a^4 b^2 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       12 I a^5 b^2 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       49 I b^4 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       99 I a b^4 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       426 I a^2 b^4 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       386 I a^3 b^4 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       279 I a^4 b^4 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       237 I a^5 b^4 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       11 I b^6 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       32 I a b^6 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       482 I a^2 b^6 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       956 I a^3 b^6 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       122 I a^4 b^6 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       360 I a^5 b^6 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       6 I a b^8 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       106 I a^2 b^8 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       354 I a^3 b^8 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       133 I a^4 b^8 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       39 I a^5 b^8 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       2 I a^3 b^10 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       51 I a^4 b^10 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       36 I a^5 b^10 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       48 I b^3 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       144 I a b^3 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       240 I a^2 b^3 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       32 I a^3 b^3 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       192 I a^4 b^3 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       48 I a^5 b^3 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       34 I b^5 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       236 I a b^5 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       936 I a^2 b^5 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       632 I a^3 b^5 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       366 I a^4 b^5 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       308 I a^5 b^5 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       60 I a b^7 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       390 I a^2 b^7 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       600 I a^3 b^7 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       236 I a^4 b^7 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       144 I a^5 b^7 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       16 I a^3 b^9 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       192 I a^4 b^9 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       56 I a^5 b^9 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       4 I b^2 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       24 I a b^2 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       8 I a^2 b^2 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       24 I a^3 b^2 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       12 I a^4 b^2 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       31 I b^4 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       346 I a b^4 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       510 I a^2 b^4 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       82 I a^3 b^4 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       245 I a^4 b^4 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       60 I a^5 b^4 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       196 I a b^6 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       580 I a^2 b^6 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       332 I a^3 b^6 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       110 I a^4 b^6 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       125 I a^5 b^6 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       42 I a^3 b^8 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       329 I a^4 b^8 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       35 I a^5 b^8 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       4 I b^3 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       96 I a b^3 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       32 I a^2 b^3 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       64 I a^3 b^3 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       20 I a^4 b^3 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       232 I a b^5 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       298 I a^2 b^5 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       56 I a^3 b^5 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       14 I a^4 b^5 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       24 I a^5 b^5 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       40 I a^3 b^7 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       255 I a^4 b^7 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       6 I a^5 b^7 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       72 I a b^4 c^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       24 I a^2 b^4 c^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       40 I a^3 b^4 c^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       4 I a^4 b^4 c^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       10 I a^3 b^6 c^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       75 I a^4 b^6 c^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       4 I a^4 b^5 c^7 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c]))/(Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 
      4 b c] (4 + b^2 + 4 b c) (-2 I - I a b + 
       a Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c])^2 (2 I - I a b + 
       a Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c])^2 (-I a b - 2 I c + 
       a Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c])^2 (-2 I b + 
       Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] - 
       Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c])^3 (-2 I b + 
       Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c])^3) + (256 I a (-1 + a c) (3 - 
       6 a^2 + 3 a^4 + a^2 b^2 - 2 a^3 b^2 c + a^4 b^2 c^2))/((2 +
        a b - I a Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c])^2 (2 + a b + 
       I a Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c])^2 (2 I - I a b + 
       a Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c])^2 (-2 I + I a b + 
       a Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c])^2) - (256 I (-1 + 
       a) a c^2 (3 a^4 - 6 a^2 c^2 + a^2 b^2 c^2 - 2 a^3 b^2 c^2 +
        a^4 b^2 c^2 + 3 c^4))/((a b + 2 c - 
       I a Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c])^2 (a b + 2 c + 
       I a Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c])^2 (I a b - 2 I c + 
       a Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c])^2 (-I a b + 2 I c + 
       a Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c])^2) + (8192 (-20 a b^3 - 
       32 a^3 b^3 + 36 a^5 b^3 - 15 a b^5 - 200 a^3 b^5 + 
       111 a^5 b^5 + a b^7 - 208 a^3 b^7 + 78 a^5 b^7 + a b^9 - 
       72 a^3 b^9 + 9 a^5 b^9 - 8 a^3 b^11 - 5 a^5 b^11 - 
       a^5 b^13 + 8 b^2 c + 24 a b^2 c + 16 a^2 b^2 c - 
       24 a^4 b^2 c - 24 a^5 b^2 c + 30 b^4 c + 82 a b^4 c + 
       212 a^2 b^4 c + 512 a^3 b^4 c - 154 a^4 b^4 c - 
       330 a^5 b^4 c + 12 b^6 c + 10 a b^6 c + 258 a^2 b^6 c + 
       1208 a^3 b^6 c - 104 a^4 b^6 c - 516 a^5 b^6 c + b^8 c - 
       8 a b^8 c + 92 a^2 b^8 c + 672 a^3 b^8 c + 32 a^4 b^8 c - 
       162 a^5 b^8 c + 10 a^2 b^10 c + 104 a^3 b^10 c + 
       32 a^4 b^10 c + 30 a^5 b^10 c + 5 a^4 b^12 c + 
       12 a^5 b^12 c - 84 b^3 c^2 - 156 a b^3 c^2 - 
       360 a^2 b^3 c^2 - 136 a^3 b^3 c^2 + 316 a^4 b^3 c^2 + 
       180 a^5 b^3 c^2 - 87 b^5 c^2 - 193 a b^5 c^2 - 
       1278 a^2 b^5 c^2 - 1870 a^3 b^5 c^2 + 665 a^4 b^5 c^2 + 
       915 a^5 b^5 c^2 - 13 b^7 c^2 - 34 a b^7 c^2 - 
       798 a^2 b^7 c^2 - 2124 a^3 b^7 c^2 - 10 a^4 b^7 c^2 + 
       684 a^5 b^7 c^2 - 6 a b^9 c^2 - 126 a^2 b^9 c^2 - 
       518 a^3 b^9 c^2 - 259 a^4 b^9 c^2 - 15 a^5 b^9 c^2 - 
       2 a^3 b^11 c^2 - 61 a^4 b^11 c^2 - 54 a^5 b^11 c^2 + 
       24 b^2 c^3 + 56 a b^2 c^3 + 48 a^2 b^2 c^3 - 
       48 a^3 b^2 c^3 - 72 a^4 b^2 c^3 - 8 a^5 b^2 c^3 + 
       162 b^4 c^3 + 578 a b^4 c^3 + 1524 a^2 b^4 c^3 + 
       460 a^3 b^4 c^3 - 934 a^4 b^4 c^3 - 430 a^5 b^4 c^3 + 
       54 b^6 c^3 + 404 a b^6 c^3 + 2232 a^2 b^6 c^3 + 
       2448 a^3 b^6 c^3 - 474 a^4 b^6 c^3 - 972 a^5 b^6 c^3 + 
       72 a b^8 c^3 + 582 a^2 b^8 c^3 + 1188 a^3 b^8 c^3 + 
       698 a^4 b^8 c^3 - 178 a^5 b^8 c^3 + 20 a^3 b^10 c^3 + 
       284 a^4 b^10 c^3 + 112 a^5 b^10 c^3 - 60 b^3 c^4 - 
       368 a b^3 c^4 - 312 a^2 b^3 c^4 + 232 a^3 b^3 c^4 + 
       244 a^4 b^3 c^4 + 24 a^5 b^3 c^4 - 81 b^5 c^4 - 
       964 a b^5 c^4 - 2178 a^2 b^5 c^4 - 474 a^3 b^5 c^4 + 
       763 a^4 b^5 c^4 + 414 a^5 b^5 c^4 - 304 a b^7 c^4 - 
       1188 a^2 b^7 c^4 - 1140 a^3 b^7 c^4 - 706 a^4 b^7 c^4 + 
       315 a^5 b^7 c^4 - 70 a^3 b^9 c^4 - 631 a^4 b^9 c^4 - 
       105 a^5 b^9 c^4 + 16 a b^2 c^5 - 16 a^3 b^2 c^5 + 
       32 b^4 c^5 + 636 a b^4 c^5 + 504 a^2 b^4 c^5 - 
       348 a^3 b^4 c^5 - 224 a^4 b^4 c^5 - 24 a^5 b^4 c^5 + 
       528 a b^6 c^5 + 1002 a^2 b^6 c^5 + 192 a^3 b^6 c^5 + 
       204 a^4 b^6 c^5 - 138 a^5 b^6 c^5 + 100 a^3 b^8 c^5 + 
       683 a^4 b^8 c^5 + 36 a^5 b^8 c^5 - 48 a b^3 c^6 + 
       32 a^3 b^3 c^6 - 324 a b^5 c^6 - 240 a^2 b^5 c^6 + 
       160 a^3 b^5 c^6 + 4 a^4 b^5 c^6 + 8 a^5 b^5 c^6 - 
       50 a^3 b^7 c^6 - 325 a^4 b^7 c^6 - 2 a^5 b^7 c^6 + 
       32 a b^4 c^7 - 16 a^3 b^4 c^7 + 4 a^3 b^6 c^7 + 
       48 a^4 b^6 c^7 + 4 I a b^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       4 I a^5 b^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       11 I a b^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       56 I a^3 b^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       39 I a^5 b^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       I a b^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       112 I a^3 b^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       50 I a^5 b^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       I a b^8 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       56 I a^3 b^8 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       13 I a^5 b^8 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       8 I a^3 b^10 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       3 I a^5 b^10 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       I a^5 b^12 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       12 I b^3 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       32 I a b^3 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       48 I a^2 b^3 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       64 I a^3 b^3 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       44 I a^4 b^3 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       64 I a^5 b^3 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       10 I b^5 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       16 I a b^5 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       134 I a^2 b^5 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       456 I a^3 b^5 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       76 I a^4 b^5 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       224 I a^5 b^5 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       I b^7 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       6 I a b^7 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       72 I a^2 b^7 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       416 I a^3 b^7 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       2 I a^4 b^7 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       132 I a^5 b^7 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       10 I a^2 b^9 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       88 I a^3 b^9 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       22 I a^4 b^9 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       8 I a^5 b^9 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       5 I a^4 b^11 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       10 I a^5 b^11 c Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       12 I b^2 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       20 I a b^2 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       24 I a^2 b^2 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       8 I a^3 b^2 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       36 I a^4 b^2 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       12 I a^5 b^2 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       49 I b^4 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       99 I a b^4 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       426 I a^2 b^4 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       386 I a^3 b^4 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       279 I a^4 b^4 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       237 I a^5 b^4 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       11 I b^6 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       32 I a b^6 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       482 I a^2 b^6 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       956 I a^3 b^6 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       122 I a^4 b^6 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       360 I a^5 b^6 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       6 I a b^8 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       106 I a^2 b^8 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       354 I a^3 b^8 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       133 I a^4 b^8 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       39 I a^5 b^8 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       2 I a^3 b^10 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       51 I a^4 b^10 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       36 I a^5 b^10 c^2 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       48 I b^3 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       144 I a b^3 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       240 I a^2 b^3 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       32 I a^3 b^3 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       192 I a^4 b^3 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       48 I a^5 b^3 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       34 I b^5 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       236 I a b^5 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       936 I a^2 b^5 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       632 I a^3 b^5 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       366 I a^4 b^5 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       308 I a^5 b^5 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       60 I a b^7 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       390 I a^2 b^7 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       600 I a^3 b^7 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       236 I a^4 b^7 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       144 I a^5 b^7 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       16 I a^3 b^9 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       192 I a^4 b^9 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       56 I a^5 b^9 c^3 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       4 I b^2 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       24 I a b^2 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       8 I a^2 b^2 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       24 I a^3 b^2 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       12 I a^4 b^2 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       31 I b^4 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       346 I a b^4 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       510 I a^2 b^4 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       82 I a^3 b^4 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       245 I a^4 b^4 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       60 I a^5 b^4 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       196 I a b^6 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       580 I a^2 b^6 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       332 I a^3 b^6 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       110 I a^4 b^6 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       125 I a^5 b^6 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       42 I a^3 b^8 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       329 I a^4 b^8 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       35 I a^5 b^8 c^4 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       4 I b^3 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       96 I a b^3 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       32 I a^2 b^3 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       64 I a^3 b^3 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       20 I a^4 b^3 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       232 I a b^5 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       298 I a^2 b^5 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       56 I a^3 b^5 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       14 I a^4 b^5 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       24 I a^5 b^5 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       40 I a^3 b^7 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       255 I a^4 b^7 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       6 I a^5 b^7 c^5 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       72 I a b^4 c^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       24 I a^2 b^4 c^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       40 I a^3 b^4 c^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       4 I a^4 b^4 c^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       10 I a^3 b^6 c^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] + 
       75 I a^4 b^6 c^6 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c] - 
       4 I a^4 b^5 c^7 Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c]))/((4 + b^2 - 
       4 b c) Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 
      
      4 b c] (2 I b - Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] + 
       Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c])^3 (2 I b + Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c] +
        Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c])^3 (-2 I + I a b + 
       a Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c])^2 (2 I + I a b + 
       a Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c])^2 (I a b - 2 I c + 
       a Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c])^2)) (b - 2 d + Sqrt[
  4 + b^2 - 4 b d]))/((2 + b^2 + 2 d^2 - 
  2 d Sqrt[4 + b^2 - 4 b d] + 
  b (-4 d + Sqrt[4 + b^2 - 4 b d])) \[Pi]^2), c > 0 && a > 0]  
 *)
```

**Edit**

For  `b>1`  you also get the right analytical (complex) result.

Answer (score 3):

Separate $x$-independent prefactor:

```
u = (b (b - 2 d + Sqrt[4 + b^2 - 4 b d]))/((2 + b^2 + 2 d (d - Sqrt[4 + b^2 - 4 b d]) + b (-4 d + Sqrt[4 + b^2 - 4 b d])) (\[Pi]^3) );
y = ((c + I x) x (-I + a x (2 c + I a x)) (b^2 (c + I x)^2 + 3 (1 + x^2)^2))/((c + I a x) (1 + a^2 x^2) (-b^2 (c + I x)^2 + (1 + x^2)^2)^2);
FullSimplify[expr - u y]
(* 0 *)
```

Use an external package

```
<< Rubi`
Assuming[c > -1 && c < 1 && d > 1 && a >= 0, yy = Int[y, x]];
res = Limit[yy /. {a -> 2, b -> 0.65, c -> 0.25, d -> 1.7}, x -> Infinity] 
- Limit[yy /. {a -> 2, b -> 0.65, c -> 0.25, d -> 1.7}, x -> 0];
r = 2 Re[u res] /. {a -> 2, b -> 0.65, c -> 0.25, d -> 1.7}
(* -0.00340441 *)
```

This is the same result as `NIntegrate` gives. One can also plot `expr` and the result of integration to make sure they are continuous.

The integrand, let us call it $f(x)$ fulfills
$$ f(-x) = f^*(x).$$

In order to get a meaningful result I further assumed that the improper integral is defined in symmetric limits, i.e.,
$$
I=\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx=\Re\left(\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx\right).
$$

**Disclaimer**

- Since the original question presents no further details, my answer
  only focuses on the integral in this narrow sense.
- I also do not attempt to answer the original question "Why?".
- The intention of this post is to demonstrate that under the    additional assumption one can get the numerical value by an analytical approach.

Comment: First, the limits of the integration are `{x, -Infinity, Infinity}`, not `{x,0, Infinity}`. Second, can you kindly explain `Re[u*res]`? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 see edits

Comment: +1. A good work.

Comment: @yarchik thank you for the amazing answer, however i need an analytic expression for the definite integral. Does your result work for any values of a,b,c,d in my original assumption? Is your solution continuous in all cases? Also, why does mathematica give the wrong result? I thought that could happen only when you compute a definite integral with the fundamental theorem of calculus with discontinuous function

Comment: @Andreas The answer is too long to paste here. Can you run the commands above? The analytical result is given by `2 Re[u res]`

Comment: @Andreas If you do not have `rubi`, you can download it here https://rulebasedintegration.org. The installation is simple and is described there as well.  Have you plotted the MA result? Maybe it is discontinuous  as you said.

Comment: @yarchik I have used Rubi following your answer, however your result is the analytical result for the antiderivative. Since i want the definite integral for all values of a,b,c,d i have to compute the limit at infinity minus the limit at zero. However I'm afraid that mathematica would do it wrong because of branch cuts in your  result, even assuming that your result is continuous for all values of the parameters. Do you see my point?

Comment: @Andreas I plotted my result obtained with `rubi` and see a perfectly continuous function for the given values of `a, b, c, d`. I do not see any discontinuity as you claim. Can you please update your question with the plot of discontinuity obtained with `rubi`?

Comment: @yarchik I am talking about generic values of a,b,c,d. For the given values the result is fine. I am asking about the generic case (not a=2 b=0.65 etc). The reason i am suspicious is that i can see why the result is fine for every possible value of the parameters

Comment: @Andreas That is why I am asking you to present such an example in you question. Please, describe you problem in detail. Even with your last comment, it is not clear what are the ranges for the constants `a, b, c, d`, are they real or complex? What is the intended use of the analytical expression? All this matters a lot and in the most generic case the answer is probably to complex to be useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128019/discussion-between-andreas-and-yarchik).

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. The command

```
result1 = Integrate[expr, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> c > -1 && c < 1 && d > 1 && 
a >= 0, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

performs a huge output under the conditions `Im[Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c]] < Re[b] &&  Re[b] < Im[Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c]] &&  Im[Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c]] + Re[b] < 0 && a > 0 && c > 0`. Now

```
Im[Sqrt[-4 - b^2 + 4 b c]] < Re[b] &&  Re[b] < Im[Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c]] && 
Im[Sqrt[-4 - b^2 - 4 b c]] + Re[b] < 0 && a > 0 && c > 0 /. {a -> 2,  b -> 0.65, c -> 0.25}
```

> `False`